# Search by Name instead of Id, c#

Tags: c#

for my products controller i have

```
namespace product2.Controllers
{
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    Product[] products = new Product[]
    {
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 },
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M },
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M }
    };

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
    {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(product);
    }
}
}
```

and in my index i have

```
var uri = 'api/products';

$(document).ready(function () {
  // Send an AJAX request
  $.getJSON(uri)
      .done(function (data) {
        // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
          // Add a list item for the product.
          $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#products'));
        });
      });
});

function formatItem(item) {
  return item.Name + ': $' + item.Price;
}

function find() {
    var id = $('#prodId').val();

  $.getJSON(uri + '/' + id)
      .done(function (data) {
        $('#product').text(formatItem(data));
      })
      .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        $('#product').text('Error: ' + err);
      });
}
```

but i want to search by Name instead of Id,

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(string name)
    {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Name == name);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(product);
    }
 }
```

does not work, i suspect products.FirstOrDefault is part of the issue, but i have tried  products.Any, but when i click just shows undefined $undefined ( function formatItem(item) {
      return item.Name + ': $' + item.Price;
    })

Comment: When you debug, what is the value of `product` in the server-side code?  What is the value of `name`?  Client-side, what is the response from the server?  Where specifically is this failing?

Comment: [works fine for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gHx7G4)

Comment: What is the error? Is it due to overloading an http method without any routing attributes to differentiate them? Or perhaps you need to do a case-insensitive comparison?

Comment: i get undefined $undefined, instead of Yo-yo $1.95
this example is on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Answer (score 0):

check your WepApiConfig.cs

make sure it has

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: 
"api/{controller}/{name}",
            defaults: new { name = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

then this is your ProductsController

```
  public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(string name)
    {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Name == name);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(product);
    }
```

then use original for your index.html

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  // Send an AJAX request
  $.getJSON(uri)
      .done(function (data) {
        // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
          // Add a list item for the product.
          $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#products'));
        });
      });
});

function formatItem(item) {
  return item.Name + ': $' + item.Price;
}

function find() {
  var id = $('#prodId').val();
  $.getJSON(uri + '/' + id)
      .done(function (data) {
        $('#product').text(formatItem(data));
      })
      .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        $('#product').text('Error: ' + err);
      });
}
```

Comment: are you answering your own question? your default route will give you more troubles  by your code. asp.net core does not know your parameter `name` from `defaults: new { name = RouteParameter.Optional }`, but it knows `action`&`id`. I would use `HttpGet["products/{name}"]` on your action `GetProduct`, instead of making a global route for a specific action.